# Multiple property declarations in the same line in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, properties

I was writing a small code project and I was wondering instead of doing:

```
 @property(readwrite, retain) NSString* make;
 @property(readwrite, retain) NSString* model;
 @property(readwrite, retain) NSNumber* vin;
```

If you could declare this all on one line, instead of multiple to have a cleaner code.

Comment: Won't necessary lead to cleaner code, but `@property(readwrite, retain) NSString *make, *model, *vin;` - actually, I think it is a pretty bad idea to do that.

Comment: Even thought that vin is an instance of NSNumber? And Why might it be a bad idea?

Comment: Having one thing per line is much easier to understand

Comment: @userXXXX actually, not. Unfortunately, I didn't even notice that it's an `NSNumber`, my bad. No, in this case you can't do it one declaration. You still can do it on one **line,** but that's truly horrible.

Comment: Btw, `readwrite` is the default so you can remove that. If you're using ARC (you should definitely use ARC), strong is also the default. So if you're trying to reduce the characters you have to type, you could take advantage of that. (`atomic` is also a default, though typically you don't want that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine property declarations that are of the same type:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *make, *model;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber *vin;
```

One disadvantage to this approach is that you can't use Xcode/Clang's documentation comments feature. For example, this:

```
/** The model of the car (e.g. Rav4) */
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *model;
```

will generate this documentation in Xcode (as well as in the sidebar and when option-clicking):

[image: Documentation comment]

If you put them on the same line, they'll get the same documentation comment (so one of them will be wrong).