# declaring multiple objects in one property

Tags: objective-c

I've noticed that many people are declaring multiple properties separately in models. Like this, for example:

```
@property ( strong , nonatomic ) NSMutableString *name;
@property ( strong , nonatomic ) NSMutableString *surname;
@property ( strong , nonatomic ) NSMutableString *fatherName;
```

I understand in case of ViewControllers we define them separately because every outlet is connected to its own object. For example:

```
@property ( weak , nonatomic ) IBOutlet UIView *view;
@property ( weak , nonatomic ) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;
@property ( weak , nonatomic ) IBOutlet UITextfield *textfield;
```

I'm wondering why everybody defines them separately. It might be because of memory management, where you'd want to declare some properties as weak and some as strong. Still, even when that isn't the case, I've never seen a single person declare properties like this:

```
@property ( strong , nonatomic ) NSMutableString *name , *surname , *fatherName ;
```

What is the reasoning behind this? I've tested the both examples I gave and they work fine. Is there something I'm missing or not understanding?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multiple property declarations in the same line in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23034691/multiple-property-declarations-in-the-same-line-in-objective-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax to declare multiple (non-outlet) properties of the same type in one line is perfectly fine. The functionality is exactly the same as the standard way to declare one property per line.